# Regexreplace forumula in Google sheets to replace multiple matches in multiple lines

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following text in Cell A1 in google sheets with multiple linebreaks:

```
A paragraph is a series of sentences
that are organized and coherent, Zing
and are all related to a single topic. 
Almost every piece of writing you do 
that is longer than a few sentences Zing
should be organized into paragraphs.Zing
... One of the most important of these 
is a topic sentence. Zing
```

And I would need to extract all the lines that ends with the word Zing so the output becomes(following is the expected output):

```
that are organized and coherent, Zing
that is longer than a few sentences Zing
should be organized into paragraphs.Zing
is a topic sentence. Zing
```

First i tried using regexextract formula `"=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".*Zing")"`, but unfortunately it returns only the 1st occurence `that are organized and coherent, Zing`

Then I tried using regexreplace to replace all other lines that doesnt contain or ends with *Zing*, but it did not work.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, ".*Zing", ",")
```

This returned:

```
"A paragraph is a series of sentences 
,
and are all related to a single topic. 
Almost every piece of writing you do 
,
,
... One of the most important of these 
,"
```

but I want the missing lines, how to exclude the above and to extract only the missed lines

I would need a formula in excel or googlesheets to match the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.*Zing)","($1)")))
```

- When you want to put each line to each row, you can also use the following formula.

  ```
    =TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.*Zing)","($1)")))
  ```

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)

Comment: it works perfect when there is a match but there is a serious issue
eg: for the string in A2: "Hello World" -- when I enter the above formula, it is expected to return null value as there is no match, but it returns the same value present in A2

Comment: @Alice Thank you for replying. In that case, for example, how about `=IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"Zing"),JOIN(CHAR(10),REGEXEXTRACT(A2,REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(.*Zing)","($1)"))),"")`? If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Comment: you are a genius, this works like charm... Thanks, this saved a lot of my time.
I had 1 more challenge, - when there are any special characters like '*' present in the cell, say A1 in the example this formula doesn't work - so as a work around, I replaced * with blanks at first and then executing this formula...